# Flutter filter list based on last week, last month and last year

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of map where there is a date field. In the screen I have filter option where I can filter data based on last week, last month and last year so Don't know how can achieve the result.

Below is my code

```
 _listOfHistory.addAll(
         _listStaticRoundForHistory.
         where((element) {
           final date = element.date;
           return date == date.subtract(Duration(days: 30));
         }
     ).toList());
```

But pretty sure that wrong.

Response Listing

```
[
 {
   "title": "title",
   "details": "details",
   "date": DateTime
 },
 {
   "title": "title",
   "details": "details",
   "date": DateTime
 }
 .
 .
 .
 .
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample example of data your have and give some examples of what output you want.

Comment: @julemand101 - Sure I just updated details

Comment: What do you mean by "last week", "last month" and "last year"?  is it -7 days for a week? and what about a month? if today is 22nd of May, what do you mean by last month, should it be data for april?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where I can filter data based on last week, last month and last year

First you need to know which day is today, in order to subtract days, months or years.

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var now_1w = now.subtract(Duration(days: 7)); 
var now_1m = new DateTime(now.year, now.month-1, now.day);
var now_1y = new DateTime(now.year-1, now.month, now.day);
```

**EDIT**
Then in your code you just need to evaluate if now is after any of the dates you are creating above, for example for 1 week:

```
where((element) {
           final date = element.date;
           return now_1w.isBefore(date);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me check the that.

Comment: I think it should be "isBefore" instead of "sAfter"

Comment: Thank you, save my day!